# Compare 2 unequal size of maps c++

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I have 2 different maps(string, string) of different size. I need to compare and return the different items present in the map.

```
eg: map1 contains
"1":"abc"
"2":"xyz"
"3":"abc"
eg: map2 contains
"1":"abcd"
"2":"xyz"
"4":"abc"
"5":"abc"
```

If you compare 2 maps, only "2" is matched. Remaining are unmatched. I need to get all unmatched into another map.

Comment: soo what do you expect here in the new map in the key `"1"`? `"abc"` or `"abcd"`?

Comment: Please provide an example output

Comment: map1 is a reference map. so my expected output will be "1":"abcd", "3":"abc", "4":"abc" and "5":"abc"

Comment: @Arun [edit]  your question and put all clarifications into the question instead of a comment.

Comment: And please also explain why you need "1":"abcd" from the second map, but not "1":"abc" from the first map, even though you do want "3":"abc" from the first map.

Comment: `std::set_symmetric_difference` should be the way to go but with a custom comparator. Also, if you're using even the values for comparison, perhaps you can use `std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` instead?

Comment: Do you want to copy all items from map1 into map2 where the key isn't already present? map1 would be default values and map2 the users input and you complete the missing entries.

Answer (score 8):

`set_symmetric_difference` should work fine:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string>
        map1 {
            { "1", "abc" },
            { "2", "xyz" },
            { "3", "abc" }
        },
        map2 {
            { "1", "abcd" },
            { "2", "xyz" },
            { "4", "abc" },
            { "5", "abc" }
        },
        map3;

    std::set_symmetric_difference(map1.cbegin(), map1.cend(), map2.cbegin(), map2.cend(),
        inserter(map3, map3.end()));

    for (auto const& p : map3) {
        std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 : abc
3 : abc
4 : abc
5 : abc
```

---

As is mentioned in a comment, if you have differing values for a single key, this version will lose one of the values. If this a problem you can make `map3` a `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` or a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` and preserve all values. [LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y2nY7V)

Comment: That is what probably I had in mind. Unfortunately I'm not working with c++ nowadays, but will happily upvote it if the code is correct

Comment: @cplusogl You don't work with C++ nowadays? That makes  your username a misnomer :(

Comment: Note that when one key is mapped to different values, one of the values is lost using this algorithm. Such as `"1":"abcd"` in the example

Comment: @eerorika I am aware of this, I but can't see any other reasonable behavior considering OP wants the output to be a map instead of something like `vector<pair<string, string>>`

Comment: @Ayxan Unless multimap is OK.

Comment: @eerorika I will add the `multimap` version. Thank you for the feedback.